# Should escaping backtick inside code be mentioned in the Markdown Help?

Tags: support, editing

Can you do this `` This is some code, and `<- this is a backtick, plus another one -> ` <- here ``? This is not as straightforward as one would think. It's matter of wrapping the code inside additional ticks like so: ``` ``This is some code, and `<- this is a backtick, plus another one -> ` <- here`` ``` (yes, triple ticking also works, to escape double ticking). But I'm sure you probably knew of this, and know when this is useful.

I didn't see this mentioned in the [Markdown Help](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) however, so had to ask in chat after trying all sorts of escaping known to me to no avail. So should this be added to the [Markdown Help](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page?

Comment: Hrm. I also think it might be a bug if \ doesn't work as an escape character.

Comment: @AnnaLear it's unconventional, I agree, but making it known in the FAQ should be enough. Not a bug certainly, a feature request maybe, which will take a long time to get implemented if it ever finds supporters. The Editor Help/FAQ can be changed in 2 minutes.

Comment: @AnnaLear working as described in spec http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code I would guess trying to handle escaping of backtick in backtick-delimited is a mess... :)